# Wordpress doesn't detect new php version

Tags: php, wordpress, ubuntu, google-cloud-platform

On Google Cloud Platform I have VM instance with Ubuntu 18.04.1 with Wordpress installed on it. In Wordpress dashboard under Site Health, it says I have PHP version 7.2.29. So I went to VM instance console and upgraded PHP with:

```sh
$ sudo su

$ add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php

$ apt-get update

$ apt-get install php7.3
```

Now when I write:

```sh
$ php -v
```

I get `PHP 7.3.16-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1`, so PHP 7.3.

So far so good. I restarted apache with `systemctl restart apache2`. Went back in Wordpress dashboard. But it still says I am running PHP 7.2, eventhough in my opinion it should detect new PHP 7.3.

I googled around but haven't got much luck. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: First thing you should understand about PHP, you can have many instances of PHP installed on one machine, not too mention PHP has 2 sides you have a CGI side that parses your webpages and CLI (Command Line) side of PHP, so just updating one side doesnt automatically update the other. Every instance of PHP can have a different version, when you type php -v you are checking the CLI side of PHP and not the CGI side

Comment: @userX Thank you! I managed to do it with a2dismod and a2enmod commands.

Comment: Yes I just googled that's the Apache Module, can you upvote my comment, thank you in advance

Comment: When you make big changes like this, it is better to restart Apache and in most cases restart the VM instance. I recommend having a test server where you verify updates to your systems first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo a2dismod php7.2
sudo a2enmod php7.3
```

then restart apache